# Removing the 'Mailed-by` header from outgoing emails

Tags: php, email, pear

I am sending emails using PHP Pear class, when I see mails in gmail, it has an Mailed-by header, I know it can be removed by using -f in php mail function, but how can I remove it in Pear send.

Comment: What is the name of the class you are using to send the emails (e.g., [`Mail`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail))?

Comment: @Architact do you have write access to the machine you are running PHP on? If so, the Mail Pear libraries are just PHP files. You can edit them and comment out the part where the header is added.

Comment: @eykanal I wouldn't stress over this. I think people will pick this up and if you look at the answers to his other questions, they mostly kind of stink.

Comment: @eykanal, on previous questions no one answered the question, those were just suggestions...I can only accept an answer if it helps me, if you think an answer must be accepted as correct one, please do let me know.

Comment: @Michael Pryor, That looks like a solution, let me check. Do you know which file should I edit (just asking :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mail Pear library is actually just a php file on your system.  I highly doubt there is a programmatic way to do what you want, but if you can't find it in the PEAR documentation you can just examine the Mail.php file yourself.

Try using the `locate` command on your system to find the Mail.php file.  It should be in /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/php/lib or something similar.  Probably under a subdirectory called PEAR.

Once you find it and if you're comfortable with this, you can edit the source file to do whatever you want (i.e. comment out the line that adds that header).  Note this will affect all PHP scripts on this system and will have to be re-added if you update PEAR.

Comment: I actually solved the problem by setting the Mail server name on server, but since your answer was another good solution, I accept it as correct.

Comment: Finding PEAR package file is way easier than using "locate", it's just `pear list-files Mail`.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
$headers["Return-Path"] = "info@yourdomain.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the PEAR mail manual page](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php), it seems like you have to specify all headers explicitly. Are you sure you're not setting `$headers['MailedBy']` elsewhere in your application? You may also want to look at [this PEAR manual (wiki) page](http://www.phpmaniac.net/wiki/index.php/Pear_Mail) for a minimal working example of the package.

Comment: `$headers['MailedBy']`, I cant find this header in pear documentation.

Comment: @architact - you won't find it in the documentation, but it's the header you said is being included in the emails. It should be somewhere in your code.